# Adding filter3d to a View3d on Away3d 4.1.6 engine breaks background rendering

Tags: actionscript-3, 3d, away3d

I’ve been trying to add the property filter3d to a view3d, while preserving an image background. I’ve instantiated a stage3DManager, as well as setting a stage3DProxy:

```
stage3DManager = Stage3DManager.getInstance(_stage);
stage3DProxy   = stage3DManager.getFreeStage3DProxy();

stage3DProxy.addEventListener(Stage3DEvent.CONTEXT3D_CREATED, onContextCreated);
```

The view3d only gets instantiated when the context3d is created:

```
away3dView = new View3D();
away3dView.stage3DProxy = stage3DProxy;
away3dView.shareContext = true;
// away3dView.filters3d = [new MotionBlurFilter3D()];     <——  (╯°□°）╯︵ ┻━┻)
```

When trying to add this line of code, it just makes the ‘background’ shrink or disappear, depending on the way the background has been created.
I’ve tried two different ways of adding the background:

Assigning a BitmapTexture to the background property on View3d results in a displacement of the background

```
view.background = new BitmapTexture(footballBackgroundBmd);
```

Using starling, as shown on this [tutorial](http://away3d.com/tutorials/Away3D_and_Starling_Interoperation), results in the removal of the background

```
starlingCheckerboard = new Starling(BackgroundImage, _stage, stage3DProxy.viewPort, stage3DProxy.stage3D);
```

Both of these methods display a background image and works nicely.
However, when adding the filters3d property on the View3d it breaks.
I understand that adding a filters3d will affect the entire view, but I do not understand what is happening with the background.

I am not entirely sure if I’m doing something completely wrong here :/

Comment: Did you have a look at this tutorial : http://away3d.com/tutorials/Away3D_and_Starling_Interoperation

From my experience, mixing two stage3d frameworks better work with manually handling the enterframe loop and specially the stage3d clear and present calls, like in the tutorial part called "Taking control - the manual approach"